# Uniqueness for autonomous ODE with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, optimal-control

Consider the following scalar ODE: for any initial data $x(0)=:x_0\in(a,b)\subset [0,1]$,
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t)=
\begin{cases}
1-x, & \text{if } x<c\\
0, & \text{if } x=c \\
-x, & \text{if } x>c
\end{cases}\\
\end{equation}
where $c\in (a,b)$. We seek for $\textbf{Caratheodory's solution}$ for all $t\geq 0$.

For existence:

i): If $x(0)\in (a,c)$: I found a solution being
$x(t)=1-(1-x_0)e^{-t}$ for $t<\tilde{t}$ and $x(t)=c$ for $t\geq \tilde{t}$ where $\tilde{t}$ is the time $x(t)$ reaches $c$ and note that $x(t)$ is strictly increasing in $(a,c)$;

ii): If $x(0)=0$, a solution is $X(t)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$;

iii): If $x(0)\in (c,b)$, a solution is 
$x(t)=x_0e^{-t}$ for $t\leq \hat{t}$ and $x(t)=c$ for all $t\geq \hat{t}$, where $\hat{t}$ is the time $x(t)$ reachese $c$. Note that $x(t)$ is strictly decreasing while it's in $(c,b)$.

However, my main concern is the $\textbf{uniqueness}$ of the Caratheodory solution to this ODE. First of all, are these solutions unique? If not, any mild conditions we can impose to restore uniqueness?

Comment: You already found that solutions that start differently flow together and are identical after some time. Thus the usual uniqueness is not satisfied. You need to define something like "forward uniqueness".

Comment: sorry I don't know what is the 'usual uniqueness'? I'm concerned with the uniqueness of the absolutely continuous solutions (knowns as Caratheodory's solutions) to the ODE, i.e. if $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are absolutely continuous and solve the above IVP $\dot{x}(t)$ with the same initial data $x_0$, then $x(t)=y(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: The usual uniqueness is bi-directional. For every initial value there is no branching going forward *or* backward. Obviously here, when the initial value is $c$ you can branch off any time going backward (as you allow solutions that are continuous and only piecewise differentiable).

Comment: Do you have $0\le a<c<b\le 1$ or how else is the interval $[a,b]$ situated relative to $[0,1]$? Is at least $c\in(0,1)$? Else your solution discussion makes no sense.

Comment: Yes! $a<c<b$ and $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$ and I only consider the forward solution if it  means to solve it for $t\geq 0$.